# Could an R-value be equal to a nullptr

Tags: c++

I have the following function in a C++ class:

`CLASS_TYPE& operator=(const char* const &&rhs)`

Could rhs ever be equal to a nullptr? In other words do I need to check in the operator definition if rhs equals to nullptr?

Comment: Why do you think it cannot be `nullptr`?

Comment: You can move something that is a null pointer, so yes

Comment: `const&&` is a bit odd.

Comment: Any pointer can be a null pointer. However "do i need to check" part depends on class and operator purpose. You certainly should check if you plan to dereference it later.

Comment: A reference cannot be null, but a reference can refer to a pointer that is null, yes.

Comment: The operator I defined in my question is used to assign a c string to the object. I was expecting you would have to pass an array to this function but like sad, a pointer can be null.

Comment: Why do you pass the pointer by `&&`-reference, instead of by value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value `nullptr` is within the possible value a pointer can take. Trying to block that from happening at compile time is futile, since you can always set the value of a pointer to `nullptr` at runtime.

If you intended to receive a non-null string literal, simply use `std::string_view` or a reference to char array:

```
// Never null
CLASS_TYPE& operator=(std::string_view rhs);

// Never null either
template<std::size_t n>
CLASS_TYPE& operator=(char const(&rhs)[n]);
```

Null is not within the possible value of either string view or a reference to char array.

Comment: string_view would be the best solution. Will look into the possibility of moving to C++17.

Comment: @Bart perfect! Also, string view has been backported as header only library for C++11 and C++14

Comment: @Bart be aware that a string view is not necessarily null terminated, and depends on the data you construct it with.

Comment: @Bart You could also move the conversion from a C string to a constructor. That constructor would automatically be used to convert a string literal to a `CLASS_TYPE` object before _move assigning_ it to the destination. No separate converting assingment operator would then be needed. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ae5M63a4e) (I used @Guillaume's operator template as a base, but the same would work for `string_view`).

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Will checkout the backport! That would help.

Comment: @TedLyngmo This is sort of what I am doing already. I am however MISRA constrained an they would like those type of conversions explicit where I would prever to just write `x = "abcd"` instead of `x = CLASS_TYPE("abcd")`

Comment: @Bart Ah, I see, the MISRA trench :-) Been there ... I'd do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/fcbeKPz6d) instead then.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the example! That would work neatly.

Comment: @Bart Re: "_Will look into the possibility of moving to C++17_" - I don't think MISRA/Autosar have released their C++17 guideline/rules yet, so I think you'll have to go for the backport of `string_view`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm already running C++14 The code checker seems to be fine with that. I think the implementors of the checker have made some additions besides the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the code as follows does indeed pass a nullptr to the function.

```
CLASS_TYPE x;
x = nullptr;
```

Checking if rhs is null is required.